# How to get SSH authentication used method in pam_exec?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, pam

I'm running a script to monitor SSH logins. I added to /etc/pam.d/sshd

```
session optional pam_exec.so seteuid    /usr/bin/tgstk login
```

and this way I'm able to access a few variables PAM_* telling me about the remote host, the logged-in user ecc...

Indeed I'm not able to access some other informations regarding the session like the authentication method (password, key, the used key). My Debian 10 server logs something into /var/log/auth.log

```
Sep  7 20:27:50 andromaca sshd[25893]: Accepted publickey for root from X.X.X.X port XXXXX ssh2: RSA SHA256:<my key here>
```

but my Ubuntu workstation doesn't act the same way: even setting

```
SyslogFacility USER
LogLevel VERBOSE
```

won't let me read anyting in the logs.

Is there any **universal** way to get this session informations, possibly not depending on logs?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out I can use

`journalctl -u ssh.service`